# Strange WordPress Japanese title in Google

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, google-search-console, cjk

I have some questions about my WordPress website. When I search the websitename or (company name) in Google, the website pops at the top of the results, but the weird thing about it, is that the title looks like this: `ＣＮ-6 ECUハーネス（受注生産） 8.5J MAZDA 【smtb-k】`

[image: See image for details]

Now I think the site is hacked, but before rebuilding the whole website, I want to know if some of you guys know, what this kind of hack (if it is a hack) this is, and how to easily remove this title from Google (let Google crawling the site again?)

FYI: the site works fine, but some of the files were infected with some strange `@include()` functions. Couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Related on Webmasters: [After site was hacked, how to remove foreign pages from Google's Index?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101371/after-site-was-hacked-how-to-remove-foreign-pages-from-googles-index)

Comment: @simo The issue is solved (5 years ago), by removing the milicious plugins. I can't actually remember which plugins caused the issue. As Stephen mentioned, installing a firewall/security plugin in Wordpress keeps problems and hacks like this almost always away. Letting Google reindexing your site and the weird results in Google will dissapear. Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

My WordPress site got hacked as well all these Japanese character links. I used two plugins to fix this:

- Anti-Malware from GOTMLS.NET (https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/)
- Wordfence Security – Firewall & Malware Scan (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)

Install, activate and scan your site. It found the files that had malicious codes so I just then removed them.

Comment: I suspect that this was downvoted because it provides plugin recommendations and looks a bit spammy because of it.  However, this answer is correct in that this problem is always caused by your site getting hacked.  Your site may work just fine for you, but hacker change it to show spam content, often in foreign languages, for Googlebot and visitors from Google.

Answer (score -1):

This attack happens most often when you install a malicious plugin or theme.

To solve this, you can either use a plugin or get your hands dirty doing it yourself.

To do it yourself, Download your entire WordPress website, most importantly all plugins and themes, then open it in any text editor of your choice, e.g., vs-code. You start by searching for some keywords.

Note: the process allows you to search sitewide to detect the culprit.

Example of keyword to search:

- The japan string you saw on google
- "wp_head" (this is the action to hook functions to the WordPress head, including meta data script and CSS)
- "wp_enqueue_script" (This is for adding js file)

And any hook or function that is needed to add code to WordPress

If you remember when these changes started, you could also narrow down on the plugin or theme you installed within those timeframes.